# Is it possible to see if the file is being dragged over the window in Kivy, Python?

Tags: python, file, kivy, drag, mouse-cursor

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to detect the situation when the user is dragging a file over the Kivy app window.

**What I already know:**

I know how to detect hovering mouse coursor over widgets (with `on_mouse_pos`), I also know how to detect if a file is dropped onto the window (with `on_file_drop`).

So, is it possible to **see whether the cursor is hovering over the window** and **"holding"** a file? Because then I want to display some prompt (eg. 'Drop HERE'). I hope you get the idea :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure, because there's this thing with SDL2 (and probably even with old pygame) when the `Window` just *pauses* (try some animation or something) when you e.g. drag it with the window decoration (the thing where title and `_ O X` are). That is the behavior if you do something with the `Window` directly.

Although, the `Window` looks like it behaves normally (doesn't pause itself), when you drag file on top of it (I tried with `examples/animation/animate.py`), to do such thing you'd need to do either the hovering behavior + handling the collisions or bind to `mouse_pos`.

However, when binding to `mouse_pos`, it seems like the `Window` still isn't capable of handling the input from outside and at the same time get mouse properties correctly (I think it's similar to the behavior when you click & drag outside of the `Window` and `Button` remains pressed, but this is kind of inversed).

**edited animate.py:**

```
class TestApp(App):

    def on_mouse_pos(self, win, args):
        print args
    ...    
    def build(self):
        ...
        from kivy.core.window import Window
        Window.bind(mouse_pos=self.on_mouse_pos)
        return button
```

Therefore if you can't get even mouse position when a mouse button is being held, I don't think such an action is possible. You can however make the areas where you want to drop the file already different (e.g. change background) when you'll expect a user to drop the file - a very dirty workaround from UI side for such a problem.

Side note: Kivy should be able to get most (if not all) `SDL2` window events via Cython, therefore if you find such event in SDL2 that would make fetching mouse position possible, such action could be performed, feel free to make a feature request in [kivy/kivy](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/) or make a pull request.